# Facebook Graph v3.3 & v4.0 Unknown Error when creating Ad Set

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to create an adset for some reason even with minimum options I cannot create the adset, the strange thing is that I can create Campaigns..
What permission or what could I be doing wrong?

You can test by creating a new campaign:

```
act_394277208131674/campaigns?name=bedding sets queen -14497 - Copy&objective=LINK_CLICKS
```

And then using that campaign id, try to create a adset:

```
act_394277208131674/adsets?name=bedding sets queen -14497 - Copy&optimization_goal=OFFSITE_CONVERSIONS&promoted_object={"pixel_id":"1262052447293125","custom_event_type":"LEAD"}&bid_strategy=LOWEST_COST_WITH_BID_CAP&billing_event=IMPRESSIONS&daily_budget=2000&campaign_id=23843801334560685&attribution_spec=[{"event_type":"CLICK_THROUGH","window_days":1}]&pacing_type=["standard"]&targeting={"age_max":65,"age_min":18,"genders":null,"geo_locations":{"countries":["GB"],"location_types":["home"]},"publisher_platforms":["facebook","instagram","audience_network"],"facebook_positions":["feed","right_hand_column","instant_article"],"instagram_positions":["stream","story"],"device_platforms":["mobile","desktop"],"messenger_positions":[],"audience_network_positions":["classic"],"targeting_optimization":"","excluded_connections":[]}&status=PAUSED&daily_budget=2000&bid_amount=30
```

Could it be permissions? It seems that fields correct.

Comment: try modify the targeting about genders, so try `"genders":[1,2]` instead of `"genders":null`

Comment: Same thing :( I tried with another account and it works, so my guess it that it could be some kind of permission, but I can't find anything different on the two accounts.

Comment: probably the `pixel_id` is not owned or be able to use by the adaccounts with ID `394277208131674`

Comment: Checked it, and the pixel is assigned to the two accounts, one that works and one that doesn't.